# Android: Populate ListView from an internal XML

Tags: android, xml, listview

I found this tutorial which makes exactly what I need :
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

The problem is that the ListView gets populated from an XML found out on an URL. What I have to change so I can load the list items (Image+Text) from an internal XML ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "internal" xml?
Is your XML file on the SD card or is it compiled in to your application as a raw resource?

Take a look at these links :

[Reading an .xml file from sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260454/reading-an-xml-file-from-sdcard)

[Android : Reading XML from local resource (for testing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111735/android-reading-xml-from-local-resource-for-testing)

The line in your code that you will need to change is :

```
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
```